# Why does my Socket IO and Phaser game keep disconnecting?

Tags: javascript, sockets

I followed a tutorial to make a basic multiplayer Phaser game and decided to see if I could run it outside my localhost. It works completely fine no (relevant) bugs on the local machine.

Once it's on the server it sometimes works for a bit but will randomly disconnect from the server and then spit a bunch of errors on reconnect. This bug can be viewed live at: http://waste.kayleegrace.space/

I have googled this error but the responses I have read go straight over my head!

Here is the server part of my server code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
});



http.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:5000');
});
```

And I connect to the server using:

```js
socket = io();
```

Comment: Please post your errors. See [mcve] please--the code shown here isn't enough to reproduce the problem. I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'isParent' of undefined` when I visit your site, which seems unrelated to the code here or socket.io. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry that was the "no (relevant) bugs " I mention but it is fixed now I believe. I cannot post an error as I don't have a physical error. As can be seen in the console the game disconnects mid play. Following this the console display some errors but I believe these are just cause by the game trying to reconnect mid game as I currently don't have it designed to do so.
I am trying to understand why my game disconnect when on the server but not on my local machines so I can fix the problem and or redesign my code to account for this.